# Find the business days between two columns in a pandas dataframe, which contain NaTs

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 columns in my pandas data frame, and I want to calculate the business dates between them.

Data:

```
 ID     On hold     Off Hold
 101    09/15/2017  09/16/2017
 102    NA          NA
 103    09/22/2017  09/26/2017
 104    10/12/2017  10/30/2017
 105    NA          NA
 106    08/05/2017  08/06/2017
 107    08/08/2017  08/03/2017
 108    NA          NA
```

I tried the below code using busday_count from numpy:

```
 df1['On hold'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['On hold'])
 df1['Off Hold'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Off Hold'])
 np.busday_count(df1['On hold'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'),df1['Off Hold'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))
```

also,

```
 np.where(pd.notnull(df1['On hold']),np.busday_count(df1['On hold'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'),
                                                df1['Off Hold'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')),0)
```

The error was :

```
   Cannot compute a business day count with a NaT (not-a-time) date
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: How do you intend to treat the days with NaT values? To be ignored or imputed?

Comment: Ignored, I want to calculate only if it is not NaT

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840812/pandas-subtracting-two-date-columns-and-the-result-being-an-integer) might have the answer

Comment: I was looking for business days between two dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below:

```
f = df1.dropna()
f['days'] = np.busday_count(pd.to_datetime(f['On hold']).values.astype('datetime64[D]'), \
            pd.to_datetime(f['Off hold']).values.astype('datetime64[D]'))

df1.merge(f[['ID', 'days']],on='ID', how='left')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [pd.bdate_range](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.bdate_range.html) method:

```
pd.bdate_range(df['On Hold'], df['Off Hold'], freq = 'B')
```

Comment: Can you share the output you got when you ran this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to drop NA first before you do bus day count. You can drop all the NA by using the following.

```
new_df = df.dropna()
```

Comment: This is just a snippet of the data, if I drop na, it will affect the other columns in the data frame.