# Get column with cumulative business day for each month from pandas datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime, datetimeindex

I am trying to get similar output to `df.index.day` but with the number corresponding to the business day. So for 2020-04-06 I want 4 instead of 6.

I appreciate the help.

Solution:

```py
for i in range(len(df_21)):
    if ((i == 0) | (df_21.month[i-1] != df_21.month[i])):
        df_21.day[i] = 1
    elif ((df_21.day[i] - df_21.day[i-1]) != 1):
        df_21.day[i] = df_21.day[i-1] + 1
```

Comment: what about using [weekday](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html)?

Comment: I want a monthly running count of weekday. I know I could hack it together, just wanted to see if there was an easy way.

Comment: so to clarify: you want to have a column showing the cumulative business days up to each row? does your datetime index also include non-business days? if so, how do you want to handle those?

Comment: Is this 4th of june or 6th of april? And if it is 4th of june, then  why would you get `6` returned? 4th of june is a thursday

Comment: @Erfan: the 6th of april is the 4th business day of april, if you sum up all business days up to and including that date

Comment: April 6th.
Yes, cumulative business days up to each row, reset each month. datetimeindex is only business days.

Comment: I just posted what I did which looks like it works.

Comment: related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903848/find-the-business-days-between-two-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-which-contain).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `datetime` column like the following, we can use `pandas.bdate_range` to check which dates are business days, then use `Series.cumsum` to get the cumulative sum:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2020-04-01', '2020-04-07')})

        date
0 2020-04-01
1 2020-04-02
2 2020-04-03
3 2020-04-04
4 2020-04-05
5 2020-04-06
6 2020-04-07
```

**Solution**

```
# get date range of business days
business_days = pd.bdate_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max())

# check which dates are business days
bdays_bool = df['date'].isin(business_days)

# get the cumulative sums of all business days per month
df['nth_business_day'] = bdays_bool.groupby([df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month]).cumsum()

        date  nth_business_day
0 2020-03-29               0.0
1 2020-03-30               1.0
2 2020-03-31               2.0
3 2020-04-01               1.0
4 2020-04-02               2.0
5 2020-04-03               3.0
6 2020-04-04               3.0
7 2020-04-05               3.0
8 2020-04-06               4.0
9 2020-04-07               5.0
```