# Trying to subtract a column of dates to another date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have the date :

```
dateTo=pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

And I would like to subtract `dateTo` to the  column of dates:

```
       number      dates      coord
AC      10      2018-07-10     11.54
AC      10      2018-07-11     11.19
AN       5      2018-07-12     69.40
```

The desired output would be a new column `df['datepond']` with the output of the subtraction. I would like this output to be integers.

What I tried was a response given here [Pandas: Subtracting two date columns and the result being an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840812/pandas-subtracting-two-date-columns-and-the-result-being-an-integer/37848869):

```
df['datepond']=(pd.Timestamp(dateTo)-pd.to_datetime(df['dates']))/ np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

In version numpy 1.12.1 it worked pretty good but im now at numpy 1.15.2 and it outputs

```
TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood
```

How could I obtain the desired output?

Comment: Can you please provide full traceback on your error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html) for remove times and for convert timedeltas to days [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df['datepond']= (pd.to_datetime('today').floor('d') - pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])).dt.days
print (df)
    number       dates  coord  datepond
AC      10  2018-07-10  11.54        97
AC      10  2018-07-11  11.19        96
AN       5  2018-07-12  69.40        95
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I can't understand why it continues outputting the same error.

Comment: @ge00rge - Hard question, for me it working nice under `numpy: 1.14.2`

Comment: @ge00rge I have numpy version `1.15.2` and the solution provided works with me

Comment: I could obtain the output, I think the problem had to do will an old version of pandas I had to upgrade, thank you, guys!