# Taking the average of date_times

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which I attached a sample of it. My goal is to find the average time that it takes to finish each process. I use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(....)
df['Start Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])
df['Finish Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Finish Time'])
df['Process'] = df['Process'].astype("category")
df['Duration'] = df['Finish Time']-df['Start Time']
sectors = df.groupby('Process')
sectors['Duration'].mean()
```

However, whenever I run the code I get the following error:

> No numeric types to aggregate

Any help would be appreciated.

File = https://filebin.net/0698p6q9or49ctw6/bb.csv?t=77zhetpd

PS: 
1. Here is the result When I used dt.days:

> A    0.5
>
> B    0.0
>
> C    0.0

But I am looking for sth like this:

> Average A = 16.54305554 hours
>
> Average B = 0.67 hours
>
> Average C = 1.37 hours

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Subtracting two date columns and the result being an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840812/pandas-subtracting-two-date-columns-and-the-result-being-an-integer)

Comment: How precise you want the mean to be? You probably want to convert datetime/timedelta to, say microseconds, and take the mean.

Comment: @G.Anderson unfortunately the result that I want is not like the one the other guy in that topic was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code and it worked:

```
df['Duration'] = (df['Duration']/np.timedelta64(1,'D'))*24
```