# Subtracting dates and only take out number of days as number

Tags: python, datetime

```
 #Under d.types i can confirm they are both datetime objects
 date1      datetime64[ns]
 date2      datetime64[ns]
```

[image]

```
 df_test['snaptoexpectedStart'] = df['date1'] - df['date2']
 TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I dont understand why I'm getting that error when both the columns im trying to subtract are in the correct format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Subtracting two date columns and the result being an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840812/pandas-subtracting-two-date-columns-and-the-result-being-an-integer)

Comment: That is what im currently trying :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has something to do with the datetime format I suppose, try casting this way to see if it works :

```
from datetime import datetime
df_test['snaptoexpectedStart'] = datetime(df['date1']) - datetime(df['date2'])
```

If you are looking to get the number of days only than try this :

```
df_test['snaptoexpectedStart'] = (df_test['date1'] - df_test['date2Date']).dt.days
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error :(

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: I tried that one too, its giving me the same error unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) class:
According to the API, subtracting two datetimes (assuming they are `datetime.datetime`s) results in a `timedelta` object. You can then use the `.day` attribute of the `timedelta` to get the difference in days.