# python - how do I get difference between two dates in integer

Tags: python, pandas

below are my codes

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['2014-03-27', '2014-03-28', '2014-03-31', '2014-04-01', '2014-04-02', '2014-04-03', '2014-04-04', '2014-04-07','2014-04-08', '2014-04-09'],
})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['days'] = df['Date'].shift(-1) - df['Date']
```

The output I get is something like this

[image]

But I want the output in the form of integer not timedelta. is there an easy way to convert in the codes?

Comment: I feel like this answer is quite on point (and also, very well solved imho) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840812/pandas-subtracting-two-date-columns-and-the-result-being-an-integer/46966942

Comment: absolutely totally agreed, it just hit the nail! thanks again @Carlo