# How to compare two data frames and keep rows of the left one based on common values and a time diff in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data that looks like below

```
saved_info = [datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 4, 23, 18, 22, 113476), 't55643', 'ab$ff$55'),
              datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 4, 23, 26, 22, 113476), 't55643', '5b$ff$15'),
              datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 4, 23, 27, 22, 133470), 't55643', 'ab$ff$55')
           ]

new_info = [('t55643', 'ab$ff$55', 44),
            ('t55643', 'be$qf$34', 33)
           ]
```

I load them into pandas as follows

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(new_info)
df1.columns = ["tid", "cid", "val"]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(saved_info)
df2.columns = ["modified_at", "tid", "cid"]
```

So the data frames look like below

**df1**

```
      tid       cid  val
0  t55643  ab$ff$55   44
1  t55643  be$qf$34   33
```

**df2**

```
                                         modified_at     tid       cid
0  datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 4, 23, 18, 22, 113476)  t55643  ab$ff$55
1  datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 4, 23, 26, 22, 112471)  t55643  5b$ff$15
2  datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 4, 23, 27, 22, 133470)  t55643  ab$ff$55
```

Now I want to get rows from `df1` that have common `cid` value with `df2` and `modified_at` value of `df2` should be greater than `15mins`

So lets say datetime right now is `2023-07-04 23:36:38` So accordingly the final result of `df1` should be

**df1 (final)**

```
      tid       cid  val
0  t55643  ab$ff$55   44
```

As you can see the `cid` value of first row of `df1` matches with the first row of `df2` and also the time diff of `modified_at` value of first row of `df2` with current time is greater than `15 mins`.

Now I can get rows of `df1` that share common value on `cid` column with `df2` by doing something like below

```
common = df1.merge(df2, on=['cid'])
df1_final = df1[(df1.cid.isin(common.cid))]
```

For comparing time diff between rows of two data frames, I found a stackoverflow answer   https://stackoverflow.com/a/46966942/5550284

But in my case I need to check a column value against the current **UTC** time and furthermore I don't know how do I chain these two conditions together.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you confirm that df2['modified_at'] contains string data of the form "datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 4, 23, 18, 22, 113476)" or does it contain a datetime.datetime object?

Comment: Its a datetime.datetime object.

Comment: Please note that is not what your saved_info data indicates.

Comment: @itprorh66 Sorry fixed it.

Comment: What do you mean by the question 'How do I chain these two conditions together"?  What two conditions? Additionally, what would the result look like if more than on row of DF2 satisfies the time delta criterion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `merge` here, just keep rows where diff is greater than 15 minutes:

```
current_time = datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 4, 23, 36, 38)
cond = current_time - df2['modified_at'] > '15m'

out = df1[df1['cid'].isin(df2.loc[cond, 'cid'])]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
      tid       cid  val
0  t55643  ab$ff$55   44

>>> cond
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: modified_at, dtype: bool
```